# Why is my largest prime factor c++ code so slow to get the final answer?

Tags: c++, optimization

I was solving a project Euler problem that requires finding the largest prime factor of a number and i used c++ to solve it
when i use the code however to get the largest prime factor for a large number (11 digits and up to be exact), the problem takes more than 3 minutes to get the final answer
what is making my code so slow ?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>



 main()
{
long long n, i, maxf=1;

 for (n=1; n<600851475143  ; n++)
 {
      bool test=true;

    if (600851475143  % n ==0)
    {
     for (i=2; i<=n/2; i++)
     {
         if (n%i == 0)
         {
             test =false;
             break;
         }
     }
     if ((test ==true) && (n > maxf))
       {maxf=n;
      cout<<n<<endl;
     }

    }

 }
 cout<<"maximum prime factor is "<<maxf<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The time complexity is making your code so slow. Your code has a time complexity of O(n²). You need a better algorithm.

Comment: A loop from 1 to 600 billion and you're wondering why it's slow? Tip: You only need to test factors up to the square root of the target value.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: project euler discourages looking up answers, but in this case there are plenty of posts on how to find prime numbers, quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with better time complexity by using the sieve of Eratosthenes method. It would reduce the overall time complexity.
You can refer the following link:

https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/sieve-of-eratosthenes.html

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing you can do to your code that will significantly improve its speed. To significantly improve its speed, change `i<=n/2` in your second for loop to take the square root of n, which would look like `i<=sqrt(n)`. This will reduce the numbers its got to test by ~99.9997% if it was going through every number.

Comment: How have you calculated `~99.9997%`?

Comment: `(n - sqrt(n))/n`, where `n = 600851475143` gives a reduction of about that much. I got 99.99987%, but whatevs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change

```
for (n=1; n<600851475143  ; n++)
```

to

```
for (n=2; n<sqrt(600851475143); n++)
```

and lateron

```
 int m = sqrt(n);
 for (i=2; i<=m; ++i)
```

Then the result will be there in milliseconds.